# Do the axioms of the Boolean algebra define its multiplication tables?

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra

If I look at the Peano axioms for arithmetic, it's clear to me how they define the addition and multiplication of every natural number with every other natural number.

Then if I look at the two element Boolean algebra, I can see again how the axioms define the truth tables for $\land$, $\lor$ and $\lnot$,  giving complete information for every unary and binary operation on the set $\{T, F\}$.

Now consider a set $\Omega$ with cardinality $n$, and look at the Boolean algebra of $\cap, \cup$ and ${}^c$ (complement in $\Omega$) on the power set $2^\Omega$. It's clear to me how the definition $X\cap Y = \{x \in \Omega | x \in X \land x \in Y\}$ can be used to give the full multiplication table for $\cap$, and similarly for $\cup$.

Is it possible to give the full multiplication table for $\cap$ and $\cup$ in $2^\Omega$ just from the axioms of the Boolean algebra of these operations?
I can see how the first and last rows and columns of the multiplication tables (for $\Omega$ and for the empty set) are defined by the axioms, and how the diagonals are defined by the axioms. It seems to me that the rest of the multiplication tables are not defined by the axioms. Is this true?
By analogy from the Peano axioms and the two element Boolean algebra I expected them to be, so I'm surprised that they appear not to be.

Should I expect the axioms of an algebra to define the full multiplication tables of its operations in general?

Comment: In general the axioms by themselves do not determine a model uniquely (or even up to isomorphism), which is also true of Peano arithmetic. Just like the axioms of a group do not by themselves determine the multiplication table for a group, etc.

Comment: Ok yes that makes sense, then I'll think of the Boolean algebra axioms as analogous to the group axioms. But when you say that 'the Peano axioms don't define a model uniquely', what do you mean?  I can see that that's true for the group axioms, but I think the Peano axioms do define every addition and multiplication operation? And the two element Boolean algebra axioms definitely do

Comment: There are nonstandard models of Peano arithmetic (models other than the natural numbers with the usual operations).

Comment: This blows my mind. Thank you.